# securely passing password through bash

Tags: bash, passwords

I am building a bash script for my work to make initial setup and windows-domain join for our Ubuntu machines easy enough for someone who  knows nothing about Linux can do it. I have found a lot of people that say that you shouldn't pass passwords through a script but to be efficient, I have to. The script prompts for info and credentials in the beginning and it needs to be able to be left to do it's job without interaction. I can't have it visible through ps when I pass it and I can't have it stored as an unsecured variable. Any suggestions?

Comment: What command(s) do you need to pass the password to?

Answer (score 7):

If you really must do this, you can read the credentials into variables with `read -s` early in the script and then pass those values to the prompts. For example:

```
read -p "Enter your username: " username
read -sp "Enter your password: " password
echo
```

*I included the blank `echo` because the `-s` option for `read` prevents the user's typing from appearing in the terminal, including the new line usually created after a user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> when answering a prompt.*

You can then use the `$username` and `$password` variables for the rest of your script and the credentials will not have to be stored outside of memory, meaning they will be lost/destroyed after the script completes.

However, note that any programs or utilities which take the credentials as command-line arguments will display those to other users on the machine running the script. For example, if I were to run a MySQL query using this method, I could do:

```
mysql -u "${username}" -p"${password}" -e "SHOW DATABASES;"
```

Other users on the machine could see the credentials while that was running with something like `ps`:

```
ps -ef | grep mysql
...
watrudoin   29512 29443  0 12:57 pts/4    00:00:00 mysql -u MyUserName -phunter2 -e SHOW DATABASES
```

You just need to be aware that what you are doing is not necessarily secure, but it seems that you already are.

Comment: Some commands allow setting the password in a config file and having the config file read from stdin allowing you e.g. the following construct: `echo "-u user\n -p $pw" | curl -K - ...` so you can pass it without being visible (don't take the curl config as-is, it's from the bottom of by head and merely to demonstrate the prinicple) - you'd have to check the commands that you need or try to select those that support this

Comment: Yes, many if not most command or utilities will include functionality like that. I included the caveat for "any programs or utilities which take the credentials as command-line arguments".

Comment: “I can't have it visible through ps when I pass it”

Comment: @Gilles -- Right, s/he wants to avoid that. That's why I included that caveat so s/he's aware that if they use the `read -s` method above and then use the variable it produces as a command-line argument that `ps` *will* display it to other users. Maybe that was just a confusing over-explanation. (Thanks for the quoting correction, by the way.)

Comment: @edaemon Just now coming across this, I enjoyed the hunter2 reference :)

Comment: By the way, how would one do this with a more frugal shell? The `-s` option seems to be specific to `bash`. I remember a long time ago I had a perl script that read the passphrase with no echoing and dumped it back on stdout to be captured, also this seems to be exactly how `ssh-askpass` behaves if it finds no X display do to its thing. Is there a simpler way?